# How do I fix this type of error System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, system.diagnostics

```
'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>

Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
    Me.cmd_View_Old_Notes = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Me.cmd_Save_Note = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Me.rpt_Viewer = New CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
```

The error in the Visual Studio 2019 IDE is

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC32035 Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement. ProjectName PathToProject\frm_Main.vb   20  Active
```

I am updating an old project from Visual Studio 2005 to VS2019. It uses VB.Net

I can't add a _ after DebuggerStepThrough()> because VS2019 removes it automatically

Comment: VB6 would not be a correct tag for this question?

Comment: Have you tried what the error message instructs?  _"Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement"_

Comment: If the attribute is to apply to the entire assembly or to the current assembly module, the attribute block remains on a separate source-code line. Precede the attribute name inside the angle brackets (< >) with Assembly: or Module: and do not add a space or underscore following the attribute block.

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

▶ Remove the space/line feed between the Attribute and the method this Attribute is applied to.

From the documentation:

[**`Error BC32035 - Attribute specifier is not a complete statement`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc32035)

> (...) An attribute block appears alone on a source-code line.
> Attributes must be applied at the beginning of a declaration
> statement, and they must be part of that statement. (...)

**`To correct this error`**:

> (...) If no declaration statement is associated with the attribute
> block, either supply one or remove the attribute block. (...)

Comment: To add to Jimi's excellent answer above, silly me couldn't figure out what else I did that it wasn't happy.  I added a new control and slapped a button on it to see where it was putting what. I had moved some things around. Try that method if you still cannot see your form in the Designer.